# Can I rollover an "individual retirement annuity" to an IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, rollover, annuity

A few years ago, my wife inherited the assets from some sort of retirement account from a deceased relative. At the time, we were less investment-literate than today, so with the aid of a financial planner, the assets were transferred into an individual retirement annuity account in my wife's name, issued by a large insurance company. Each year, she is required to take required minimum distributions from the annuity (I believe due to the age of the relative that she inherited the account from), which show up as taxable income for us (that we don't really need at this point in time).

I would like to avoid the required distributions, obtain greater choice of investments, and in general consolidate our investment picture by moving these assets into a different account structure. It would seem to make sense to roll the assets over into a traditional IRA (she already has one from rolling over a previous employer's qualified retirement plan contributions). Is this possible without significant penalties? I understand that redemption of the annuity has a surrender charge associated with it, but I'm wondering if I can make the move without incurring adverse income tax consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to take a retirement account and move it into the beneficiary's name, an inherited IRA is titled as "Deceased Name for the benefit of Beneficiary name".
Breaking the correct titling makes the entire account non-retirement and tax is due on the funds that were not yet taxed. If I am mistaken and titling remained correct, RMDs are not avoidable, they are taken based on your Wife's life expectancy from a table in [Pub 590](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590.pdf), and the divisor is reduced by one each year.

Page 86 is "table 1" and provides the divisor to use. For example, at age 50, your wife's divisor is 34.2 (or 2.924%). Each year it decrements by 1, you do not go back to the table each year. It sounds like the seller's recommendation bordered on misconduct, and the firm behind him can be made to release you from this and refund the likely high fees he took from you. Without more details, it's tough to say. I wish you well.

The only beneficiary that just takes possession into his/her own account is the surviving spouse. Others have to do what I first described.

Comment: I suspected that may be true. [This article seems to agree with your assertions also](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052970204083204577080180888026916.html). Looks like it's going to have to stay where it is; turning the entire account into taxable income in one year would be extremely cost-prohibitive.

Comment: What exactly was it in when her mom passed? That's what's not clear to me.

Comment: I do not recall. She inherited the account nearly four years ago, and my memory does not serve me well enough to remember. Her relative had a number of retirement accounts of varying types that have each had to be treated separately; I believe this one may have been a traditional IRA (that we were recommended to convert into this annuity structure), but I'm not sure.

Comment: You may be able to make the move, provided the titling is done correctly. An inherited IRA can be transferred between brokers and invested in what you wish, aside from the usual disallowed investments. IRAs are already tax favored, putting an annuity inside an IRA is generally considered ill-advised, what was the reason behind that move?

Comment: The only reasoning was a recommendation from a financial advisor (who I'm sure cherry-picked the product that was most financially advantageous to him) and our youthful ignorance. I need to track down the contract terms; I'm not sure when/if we are required to start taking larger pieces out. I didn't take much interest in investing until after the events of 2008, and if I had it all to do over again, I would have handled the situation differently.

Comment: The amount withdrawn each year from a non-spousal Inherited IRA must be **at least** as large as Required Minimum Distribution as set by the IRS rules and tables. My guess is that the financial advisor took *all* the money out of the IRA and bought a tax-deferred annuity with it (less of course a generous commission), and the money that is being received is from the annuity. If so, the annuity's rules will govern, not IRA rules; there will likely be big surrender fees to get out from it, and I don't think what you can get out after surrendering the annuity can be rolled over into an IRA.

Comment: Dilip - I believe that such a maneuver (i.e. selling out an IRA, which is a nice tax deferred account) to put into an annuity, is Financial Malpractice, and the OP needs to decide if he wishes to pursue. Depends how much money is involved.

Comment: @Dilip: Nice to see you over on this site also, and thanks for your perspective. I'm a bit confused by the structure of the account, as it's termed an annuity and has a "surrender charge," (about 4% of the account's assets) but it does behave similarly to an IRA (i.e. the distributions that we receive each year are RMDs, calculated using the associated equation). I do not believe that the tax-deferred account was cashed out; we didn't receive a 1099-R indicating the large tax bill that would have resulted from that. This sounds like a somewhat unique product that I should learn more about.

Comment: I need to research more, but there's two criteria, suitability, which here, I doubt, and 'understanding' which is always fuzzy. The fact that you don't quite know what this product is, sets off a compliance red flag.

Comment: Jason: If your wife were getting distributions each year from an inherited IRA, she would definitely be getting a 1099-R from the IRA custodian, with a code (4? in Box 7?) indicating that this was taxable income to your wife ,but no 10% penalty for premature withdrawal was required because the distribution was being made on account of the death of the owner. Also, I believe that IRA custodians are required to withhold 20% of the distribution and send it to the IRS as income tax withheld, or maybe that's just my IRA custodian. Check if income tax was withheld from the payments.

Comment: Jason: I believe more and more that the advisor rolled over the IRA money into what is called single-payment tax-deferred annuity. No income tax was charged when the money was rolled over (it retained its tax-deferred status), but payments from the annuity are, of course, taxable income. I don't think a rollover of any kind will help. RMDs *have* to be taken (there is a 50% penalty on the amount not withdrawn in timely fashion plus income tax has to be paid too on the unwithdrawn amount, so nobody opts to refuse taking th RMD), and this will not change even if you shift the account elsewhere.

Comment: Dilip, excellent comments. I'd only note, the 20% is not required on this kind of RMD, in my case, the withdrawal form offers whatever withholding I'd like. For an old client, this lets us withhold her entire tax bill for the year out of this RMD taken in December, and not bother with quarterly estimates.

Answer (score 1):

Annuities, like life insurance, are sold rather than bought.

Once upon a time, IRAs inherited from a non-spouse 
required the beneficiary to

(a) take all the money out within 5 years, or

(b) choose to receive the value of the IRA at the time of 
the IRA owner's death in equal installments over the expected 
lifetime of the beneficiary.

If the latter option was chosen, the IRA custodian issued the 
fixed-term annuity in return for the IRA assets. If the IRA 
was invested in (say) 15000 shares of IBM stock, that stock 
would then belong to the IRA custodian who was obligated to 
pay $x per year to the beneficiary for the next 23 years (say).
There was **no investment** any more that could be transferred 
to another broker, or be sold and the proceeds invested in
Facebook stock (say).  Nor was the custodian under any 
obligation to do anything except pay $x per year to the 
beneficiary for the 23 years.

Financial planners loved to get at this money under the
old IRA rules by suggesting that if all the IRA money were
taken out and invested in stocks or mutual funds through 
*their* company, the company would pay a **guaranteed** $y 
per year, would pay more than $y in each year that the 
investments did well, would continue payment until the 
beneficiary died (or till the death of the beneficiary 
or beneficiary's spouse - whoever died later), and would
return the entire sum invested (less payouts already made,
of course) in case of premature death. $y typically would
be a little larger than $x too, because it factored in some earnings
of the investment over the years. So what was not to like?
Of course, the commissions earned by the planner and the
lousy mutual funds and the huge surrender charges were 
always glossed over.